# Using geom_polygon or geom_rect to plot multiple x and y errors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset where the errors have the following x1 (age min), x2 (age max), y1 (height min), y2 (height max) and make a trapezium shape like this plot.

[image: desired plot]

I want to do the same and plot these as errors and then have the gaussian process mean and error from a different model showing. To plot the errors as trapezium shapes I think I can do this using `geom_polygon` but I can't work out how to get the polygons to plot. It looks like you have to manually specify all of the coordinates see https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_polygon.html . This seems extremely time-consuming to do for over 20 data points. Does anyone know of a more concise way to do this?

N.B. I have flipped the coordinates for the plot - this can be a bit confusing

Thanks,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidypalaeo)

### Create graph

ggplot(WAPRSL, aes(x =RSLc, y = Age))+
  labs(x = "RSL (m)",y="Age (AD)")+
  theme_classic()+
  geom_lineh(data = WAPRSLgp, aes(x=mean,y=Age),col="#227988")+
  coord_flip()+
  geom_ribbon(data = WAPRSLgp, aes(x=mean, xmax=mean+error, xmin=mean-error), fill="#227988",alpha=.5)+
  geom_ribbon(data = WAPRSLgp, aes(x=mean, xmax=mean+error*2, xmin=mean-error*2), fill="#227988",alpha=.7)+
geom_polygon(data=WAPRSL, aes(c(x1,x2,x2,x1),c(y1,y1,y2,y2))) ### something like this?
```

current plot without polygons

[image: current plot]

### Data

```
### WAPRSL data
structure(list(depths = c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5), RSL = c(0.162319931, 
0.170053941, 0.166157744, 0.268604159, 0.173369111, 0.207652794
), RSLerror = c(0.084355046, 0.084524909, 0.084307832, 0.084389419, 
0.0838797, 0.083901714), Age = c(2017.393323, 2015.935137, 2013.065412, 
2008.534508, 2004.853771, 2001.797776), Ageerror = c(0.183297248, 
0.303357588, 0.566892665, 1.183257304, 2.427930603, 2.481236284
), RSLc = c(0.162319931, 0.16973314, 0.165205604, 0.26665522, 
0.17061041, 0.204221774), y1 = c(2017.210026, 2015.631779, 2012.498519, 
2007.351251, 2002.42584, 1999.31654), y2 = c(2017.57662, 2016.238495, 
2013.632305, 2009.717765, 2007.281702, 2004.279012), x1 = c(0.162360256, 
0.169799879, 0.16533032, 0.266915536, 0.171144554, 0.204767646
), x2 = c(0.162279606, 0.169666401, 0.165080887, 0.266394903, 
0.170076265, 0.203675902)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")


### WAPRSLgp data 

structure(list(Age = 1832:1837, mean = c(-0.098482271, -0.09855201, 
-0.098622714, -0.098572523, -0.098894533, -0.099396926), error = c(0.054412551, 
0.053483911, 0.052543897, 0.051595228, 0.05064071, 0.049683294
), min = c(-0.152894822, -0.152035921, -0.151166611, -0.150167751, 
-0.149535243, -0.14908022), max = c(-0.04406972, -0.045068098, 
-0.046078817, -0.046977296, -0.048253822, -0.049713632)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `x1`, `x2`, `y1` and `y2` points describe a perfect rectangle. Hence, the easiest thing is to simply use `geom_rect()`. I've commented out some lines since the `WAPRSLgp` data seems to describe a different part of the x-axis. The examples assume the `WAPRSL` data is in the global environment.

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.0.5

ggplot(WAPRSL, aes(x =RSLc, y = Age))+
  labs(x = "RSL (m)",y="Age (AD)")+
  theme_classic()+
  # geom_line(data = WAPRSLgp, aes(x=mean,y=Age),col="#227988", orientation = "x")+
  coord_flip()+
  # geom_ribbon(data = WAPRSLgp, aes(x=mean, xmax=mean+error, xmin=mean-error), fill="#227988",alpha=.5)+
  # geom_ribbon(data = WAPRSLgp, aes(x=mean, xmax=mean+error*2, xmin=mean-error*2), fill="#227988",alpha=.7) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = x1, xmax = x2, ymin = y1, ymax = y2),
            fill = "transparent", colour = "black")
```

[image]

However, if you insist on polygons, you'd need to reshape your data a bit.

```r
WAPRSL$id <- seq_len(nrow(WAPRSL))

poly <- tidyr::pivot_longer(WAPRSL, y1:y2, names_to = "y_var", values_to = "y_val")
poly <- tidyr::pivot_longer(poly, x2:x1, names_to = "x_var", values_to = "x_val")
# Correct for the order
poly <- poly[(poly$id - 1) * 4 + rep(c(1,2,4,3), max(poly$id)), ]

ggplot(WAPRSL, aes(x =RSLc, y = Age))+
  labs(x = "RSL (m)",y="Age (AD)")+
  theme_classic()+
  # geom_line(data = WAPRSLgp, aes(x=mean,y=Age),col="#227988", orientation = "x")+
  coord_flip()+
  # geom_ribbon(data = WAPRSLgp, aes(x=mean, xmax=mean+error, xmin=mean-error), fill="#227988",alpha=.5)+
  # geom_ribbon(data = WAPRSLgp, aes(x=mean, xmax=mean+error*2, xmin=mean-error*2), fill="#227988",alpha=.7) +
  geom_polygon(
    data = poly,
    aes(x = x_val, y = y_val, group = id), 
    fill = NA, colour = "black"
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>